# Construct hex string "\xc2" in R Language

Tags: r

I am trying to convert "<c2>" string into raw `c2`. I tried replacing the greater than sign with empty string and less than sign with "\x" but I always get 2 backslashes, i.e. "\\xc2"

```
original_string <- "<c2>"
temp1 <- sub("<", "\\x", original_string, fixed = TRUE)
bad_hex_string <- sub(">", "", temp1, fixed = TRUE)

identical(
  charToRaw(bad_hex_string),
  as.raw(c(0x5c, 0x78, 0x63, 0x32))
)

good_hex_string <- "\xc2"
identical(
  charToRaw(good_hex_string),
  as.raw(0xc2)
)
```

Comment: You can't use paste to build the string because "\xc2" is literally one character long. It's not made up of three separate characters. Why are you trying to paste such a value? "\xc2" is a single byte with value 194. You can also do `identical(as.raw(194),as.raw(0xc2))` if you need to create bytes with their numeric value.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, the reason of this is that I received json data that has hex strings wrapped with less than and greater than signs, e.g. "<c2>", hence my ultimate goal is to convert it into a raw `c2`

Comment: Well then maybe you can edit your question to show the problem that you are actually trying to solve. Show the input and the desired output. If you have hex values, you can convert them to numeric values with `strtoi("0xc2")` and if you need to get to raw then `as.raw(strtoi("0xc2"))`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I edited my question.

Comment: Is the entire input string always made up of these escapes values? Are you only interesting in converting to raw? Or do you need to convert to strings?

Comment: Some of them are wrapped by <> and some are not, this is an example data   [
    "\u0002",
    "<c2>",
    "<82>",
    "<d4>",
    "c",
    "L",
    "<a5>",
    "<d1>",
    "<ef>",
    "<a1>",
    "R",
    "F",
    "<c2>",
    "R",
    "c",
    "<ac>",
    "1",
    "~",
    "y",
    "*",
    " ",
    "p",
    "<d2>",
    "D"
  ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236165/discussion-between-edgar-manukyan-and-mrflick).

Comment: So you have an array of strings that are meant to be interpreted as single character bytes, and you want to return a raw vector as a result? That's some crazy input.

Answer (score 0):

I agree @MrFlick, the input is not standardized. Your hint actually did the job, thank you ever so much!

```
original_string <- "<c2>"
temp1 <- sub("<", "0x", original_string, fixed = TRUE)
good_hex_string <- sub(">", "", temp1, fixed = TRUE)

identical(
  as.raw(strtoi(good_hex_string)),
  as.raw(0xc2)
)
```